# Should I be using arrayfun in Matlab like this?

Tags: matlab

I started learning a little Matlab a couple days ago.

I wanted to plot a Dirac-comb-like approximation, so given that I knew some functional programming, and that I have been told "you shouldn't need `for` loops in Matlab", I ended up with this:

```
M = 50
dx = 0.1
r = 20
x = -r/dx:r/dx
y = arrayfun(@(k) dx .* sum(exp(-2j * pi * dx * k * (-M:dx:M))), x)
```

But I feel `arrayfun` isn't a good way to do this -- it just feels awkward/overkill in Matlab.

Or maybe it's just me, I don't know.
Is there a better way to plotting this graph without resorting to `arrayfun`, or is this the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use semicolons behind commands to suppress output, it really makes a difference in performance:

```
M  = 50;
dx = 0.1;
r  = 20;
x  = -r/dx : r/dx;
```

Then, dot-operators (`.*`, `./`, etc.) are for element-wise operations. The multiplication you do inside the arrayfun (`dx .* sum(exp(...))`) is a scalar times a vector. In this case element-wise and normal multiplications are the same. It is a good habit to keep normal multiplications for scalar*vector; it helps prevent bugs.

Then, the `arrayfun` is unneccesary. You can accomplish the same like so:

```
y = dx * sum( exp(-2j*pi*dx * (-M:dx:M).'*x) );
```

The product `-2j*pi*dx` is a product between all scalars. The product `(-M:dx:M).'*x` however is a product between matrices. Since `sum` sums down the columns (dimension 1) by default, the results are the same. This solution has larger memory overhead, but is *a lot faster* than `arrayfun`.

Note that I've used `.'` for transpose. In Matlab, the notation `A'` means conjugate transpose, and `A.'` means normal transpose. Especially in the context of complex math like you have, this is very important. Learn the difference, and remember it well.

Comment: +1 this is an awesome answer/advice, thank you! Just to clarify, when you say `exp((-M:dx:M).' * x)` -- is that supposed to be a [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential), or is it doing something else? I've never used matrix exponentials for this!

Comment: @Mehrdad: No, `expm()` is the matrix exponential. `exp( [some matrix] )` is just the element-wise exponential.

Comment: Ahhhh that makes more sense, I was wondering how to do that! Thank you! :)